# How to set Role Hierarchy in Spring Security 6.1.0 (Spring Boot 3.1.0)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

recently i wondered how to make Role Hierarchy work in Spring Security 6.0.2 without writing beans like

```
@Bean
public AuthorityAuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext>
        guestAuthorityAuthorizationManager() {
    AuthorityAuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext>
            objectAuthorityAuthorizationManager =
                    AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority(GUEST.getRole());
    objectAuthorityAuthorizationManager.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return objectAuthorityAuthorizationManager;
}
```

for a common flat role hierarchy, like `ADMIN > USER > STAFF > GUEST`.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to Spring 6.1.0 (which comes with Spring Boot 3.1.0 dependency train) the solution is just to introduce `RoleHierarchy` bean like

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    hierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST");
    return hierarchy;
}
```

and Spring will use it automatically.

example:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests ->
   authorizeHttpRequests
      .requestMatchers(
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(ACTUATOR_URL_PATTERN),
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGIN_2FA_FIRST_STEP_URL_PATTERN),
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGIN_2FA_SECOND_STEP_URL_PATTERN),
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGIN_FORM_URL_PATTERN),
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(OAUTH_URL_PATTERN),
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(PASSWORD_URL_PATTERN)
      )
      .permitAll()
      .requestMatchers(
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGOUT_URL_PATTERN)
      )
      .hasRole("GUEST")
      .requestMatchers(
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(ADMIN_URL_PATTERN),
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(API_URL_PATTERN),
         new AntPathRequestMatcher(MAILING_URL_PATTERN)
      )
      .hasRole("ADMIN")
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated());
```

note that

- `.hasRole()` does not have a "ROLE_" prefix
- moreover, now you need to use configurer inside brackets of `http.authorizeHttpRequests(...)` (i use lambda here). RoleHierarchy is used here under-the-hood.

enjoy!